# Registration for talks "is" or "are" free?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which is the proper usage in this sentence:

> Registration for talks is free.

or

> Registration for talks are free.

Comment: Registration is a singular noun, so it's "is."  Talks is plural, but registration is the subject.  Talks is the object of the preposition "of."

Answer (score 2):

In the sentence "Registration for talks is/ are free" "is" is the correct word to be used since the verb "to be" here is referring to the singular word "Registration".